# Limit taxonomy terms display on hierarchical select

Tags: rules, taxonomy-terms

I need to limit the taxonomy terms visible in a field type 'taxonomy term' using the module 'hierarchical_select' when creating a post.

There is a way to do this?

1. I have a vocabulary called 'cities' in this format:

   - state
     -- City 1
     -- City 2
2. I have a content type called 'condominiums' and this type of content I have a field called 'city' of type 'taxonomy term' (vocabulary cities) using the HS module.
3. I have a user with role 'city' and in this paper there is also a field called 'city' of type 'taxonomy term' (vocabulary cities) using the HS module.
4. I need the user with role 'city' look in the 'city' (when you create a new content) only city that is attributed to him.

Something like:

1. superadmin user (city 1) can see:

   - state
     -- City 1
     -- City 2
2. user city (city 2) can see:
   state-
   -- City 2

Tanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Workbench Access](http://drupal.org/project/workbench_access) module might be a great solution for your issue.

> Workbench Access creates editorial access controls based on hierarchies. It is an extensible system that supports structures created by other Drupal modules.
>
> The module supports Taxonomy and Menu modules for the management of access hierarchies.

Also, take a look at the current [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1905332) for Hierarchical Select module integration with Workbench Access module